# How do I get the Windows 7 Firewall to prompt me whether to allow or deny a new connection?

Tags: windows-7, firewall, windows-firewall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure the Windows 7 firewall to prompt me on outbound traffic?](https://superuser.com/questions/217551/how-can-i-configure-the-windows-7-firewall-to-prompt-me-on-outbound-traffic)

In Vista and before, new programs attempting an ingoing or outgoing connection would cause a Windows prompt whether to allow or deny the program as a rule.

In Windows 7 I seem to have to manually enter rules. Is there any way to get Windows 7 to ask me on its own?

**Edit** : The options MrStatic points to in his answer are already turned on. No prompts, hence my question. See [this forum entry](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprosecurity/thread/8c227cbf-6328-4867-a37f-fe244621af83) for another guy with the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The windows firewall generally sucks horribly.  I had trojan just last month that bypassed it and was sucking all my bandwidth sending something.(I think it was actally trying to take everything) the windows firewall really only blocks incoming connections.  if something wants to send something windows isn't going to stop it one bit.

I use Comodo firewall now,  although honestly it can be set to the most paranoid settings its rediculous. it even can be set to the point of letting you know every time a process starts and when one file is calling another or when a program wants to write to disk.  I went through a few before I got to this one and I'm happy with it (i turned off all those rediculous settings, it just tells me about unusual things)

and to answer your question, not really. other than what you have its 90% manual and it doesn't block outgoing(not really)

Comment: Comodo has a free version which is great (the *free* part) but it's not perfect. I've never had security problems with it but for ravaging CPU and conflicting with other very popular AV (AVG & Avast) it can be a pain

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it is possible to do it any other way in Windows 7.

Take a look at [Windows 7 Firewall Control](http://www.sphinx-soft.com/Vista/index.html). This basically provides more control over the Windows 7 firewall. It will notify you of any application that is blocked. You can then change its permissions. The free version should suffice for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Firewall\Customize Settings`

When you goto the control panel for the windows firewall its on the top left with the first UAC shield.

[image: Firewall panel]

Comment: those checkboxes are already on, but it still doesn't prompt me. I have the same problem as here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprosecurity/thread/8c227cbf-6328-4867-a37f-fe244621af83