# Internet via tethering: How to limit PC internet usage?

Tags: windows, internet, android, bandwidth, tethering

Occasionally, I need to tether my android phone to my laptop to get internet. I have very little mobile internet (500MB /month) and it can disappear very quickly. I need a few tips on how to use force windows and all applications to use as little bandwidth as possible.

Here's what I do:

- Close all programs running in system tray
- Turn off windows udpate
- Use opera with "Opera turbo" and turn off flash

Any more tips? Especially a program that would block EVERYTHING from accessing the internet except the browser and another program occasionally (skype)?

I just closed all programs and updates and tethered my laptop today. Within a few seconds doing of nothing, it downloaded 20MB over 3G.

Comment: Disappointing this was marked as a duplicate question. The answers are poor at best (tedious to use). Using something like `NetLimiter` (a Windows application) would be much more user friendly for @David. You simply set all connections to be blocked by default and then enable processes / executables to connect to the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a firewall.  Most firewalls of today are configured to disallow incoming connections, but you can just as easily configure them to block outbound connections as well.  Windows includes a free firewall that you merely have to enable, called, appropriately enough, "Windows Firewall."

You want to disallow everything except a list of what you want to be able to get through--this is called a "whitelist."  The Windows firewall doesn't make this very simple, but it is possible.  Check out the Super User thread [over here](https://superuser.com/questions/217551/how-can-i-configure-the-windows-7-firewall-to-prompt-me-on-outbound-traffic) for details.  Alternatively, just install a better firewall, and configure it to prompt you for outgoing traffic.