# Botnet/Virus Removal?

Tags: virus, malware

I am not sure what type of virus I have on my computer, and I am not sure if this is the right site to ask this type of question on, but here it goes:

About a month ago I downloaded something i believe to be the source of my issue and most likely contained a trojan horse. i noticed some unusual activity from this program called peerblock - an IP detecting and blocking program that i use frequently. Unusual IP sources ranged from "Ministry of Defense" to "Botnet Russia" to "Limelight Co.". These attempted connections were all blocked from peerblock, but i still found it weird so i unplugged Ethernet and left it alone for a couple days.

After about a week, i turned my computer on and was greeted with this same spamming of attempted IP connections from these "botnets". I noticed my PC was much slower and and i began to get ad malware without even downloading anything.

A few days later, I noticed my laptop getting these same IP connections from Peerblock. These issues still occur and havent been fixed. i also noticed my phone acting strange too. I reset my HTC M8 to factory settings due to its constant shutting off, failed incoming/outgoing texts, and battery loss. This reset fixed the problem, so i decided to reset my PC, as i believed the botnet may have spread to my phone somehow and could be removed the same way i did on my phone.

So now here i am, 2 restores later, and my PC is still detecting IP connections from odd sources such as "Pakistan Education and Research Network" and "Telephia", companies i have never heard of. Also, my PC is shutting off at random times during use, which didnt happen before i reset.

However, i was required to reset to win 8.1 Enterprise evaluation edition as win8.1 pro cant be restored to factory settings. Could this be a reason to the random shut offs?

Sorry for the long question, but i really would appreciate an answer :) Thanks!

Comment: IP Destinations or Sources? If you are seeing random IPs attempting to access your computer, this is nothing new. Make sure you are connected to a router with a firewall if you are currently plugged directly into your modem. If your computer is attempting to contact random IPs, that's when you should be concerned about malware.

Comment: Yes my pc is attempting to connect to other IPs. Any suggested programs that can stop/detect the source of this issue?

Comment: Why do you have PeerBlock in the first place? Torrenting? If so, are you sure your Torrent client isn't just set to auto-start with Windows?

Comment: What wud auto start utorrent do?

Answer (score 1):

The weirdness with your phone is completely unrelated to the problems with your PC.

Modern malware won't cause random shut-offs (at least not on purpose), nor will switching to Windows Enterprise or Pro. Random, complete shut-downs are most often a hardware issue, perhaps overheating (when was the last time you cleaned the intake and exhaust vents, and the fan?).

Anyhow, to identify what's making the calls from you PC you could try using Windows' [NetStat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) utility (`NetStat -ab`) to get a list of active connections and which local processes are using each connection.

Additionally, you may want to try and configure Windows' firewall to warn you on outgoing connection attempts. For info on that perhaps check out this SU question: [How can I configure the Windows 7 firewall to prompt me on outbound traffic?](https://superuser.com/questions/217551/how-can-i-configure-the-windows-7-firewall-to-prompt-me-on-outbound-traffic)

If you're *convinced* it's malware, and/or you prove it, then follow this SU question for advice on removal: [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)