# How to block all outbound connections in windows 8.1 for a specific WIFI connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, firewall

I'm travelling around and use lot's of different Wifi connections. When using a general wifi connection everything is allowed.

There is only 1 connection (a wifi hotspot connection to my mobile phone which is connected to the mobile provider) which I would block everything except chrome browsing.

The reason for this is that I have to pay for the mobile connection from my phone to the provider. So i really need to minimize the use of data.

How to do this? I tried to add rules in windows firewall but cannot add a new profile and/or a new group. Also cannot select the wifi connection name. Is there a property which I can use to apply the rule?

If not, is there another app who can easily do this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so my first answer was not exactly helping so I tried googling it and it turns out that Windows Firewall can't filter like that, you would have to download some kind of firewall control, see this Super User thread:

[How can I configure the Windows 7 firewall to prompt me on outbound traffic?](https://superuser.com/questions/217551/how-can-i-configure-the-windows-7-firewall-to-prompt-me-on-outbound-traffic)

I also found out that if you don't want to download any software, you could easily limit your PC's data usage while tethering, there is a lot of ways to do this so I'm going to link the websites so you can read it for yourself.

[Howtogeek - How to Make Your Computer’s Browser Use Less Data When Tethering](http://www.howtogeek.com/138658/how-to-make-your-computers-browser-use-less-data-while-tethering/)

[PCWorld - How to limit your PC's data usage while tethering](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2853758/how-to-limit-your-pcs-data-use-while-tethering.html/)

And finally, how to set a wifi connection to metered in Windows 10:

[Tenforums - Set Wireless Network as Metered or Non-Metered Connection in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3162-wireless-network-metered-connection-set-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer you're looking for, if not please try and edit your question because it's very hard to understand.

Comment: This is not a good solution. The screen above is for all WIFI connections. If i have a WIFI connection through any hotel it should allow everything. If I have a WIFI connection by tethering on my mobile is should only allow chrome.

Comment: Your phone can't choose what data your pc can use. If you only allow chrome on your phone, your pc will still be able to use everything.

Comment: The howtogeek link is not a good solution as it is to much work if i switch between wifi connections. I applied the tenforums link. Good start, the connection is now on variable cost. But still not completly minimized. It is no problem to download other software as long it is free or on donation basis.